# Deducing a lattice is modular.

Tags: abstract-algebra, congruences, lattice-orders, semigroups, magma

This is (the second part of) Exercise 2.6.4 of Howie's *"Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory"*. The first part is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976431/if-lambda-subseteq-mathscrl-rho-subseteq-mathscrr-then-lambda-circ-r).

### The Details.

> **Definition 1:** A lattice $(L, \le, \wedge, \vee)$ is *modular* if, for all $a, b, c$ in $L$,
> $$a\le c\implies (a\vee b)\wedge c=a\vee(b\wedge c).$$
>
> **Definition 2:** The set of congruences on a semigroup $S$ is denoted $\mathcal C(S)$.
>
> **Proposition 1.8.3** (of Howie's book): Let $\mathcal K$ be a sublattice of the lattice $(\mathcal C(S), \subseteq, \cap, \vee)$ of congruences of a semigroup $S$, and suppose that $\rho\circ\sigma=\sigma\circ\rho$ for all $\rho, \sigma$ in $\mathcal K$. Then $\mathcal K$ is a modular lattice.
>
> **Definition 3:** We define, for an arbitrary equivalence $E$ on a semigroup $S$, $$E^{\flat}=\{(a, b)\in S\times S : (\forall x, y\in S^1) (xay, xby)\in E\}$$ as *the largest congruence on $S$ contained in $E$.*
>
> **Lemma 1:** Let $S$ be a semigroup, let $\lambda$ be a right congruence on $S$ contained in $\mathcal L$ and let $\rho$ be a left congruence on $S$ contained in $\mathcal R$. [Then $\lambda\circ\rho=\rho\circ\lambda$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976431/if-lambda-subseteq-mathscrl-rho-subseteq-mathscrr-then-lambda-circ-r)

### The Question:

> Deduce (from **Lemma 1**), using Proposition 1.8.3, that the sublattice $[1_S, \mathcal{H}^{\flat}]$, consisting of all congruences on $S$ contained in $\mathcal H$, is modular.

### My Attempt:

I haven't got anywhere. It should be a simple application of the proposition.

Please help :)

Comment: Any congruence contained in $\mathcal H$ is both a left congruence and a right congruence, and is contained in both $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal R$. Hence any two congruences contained in $\mathcal H$ permute, according to the Lemma. The Proposition now gives modularity.

Comment: @KeithKearnes That should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Keith Kearnes in the comments:

> Any congruence contained in $\mathcal{H}$ is both a left congruence and a right congruence, and is contained in both $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{R}$. Hence any two congruences contained in $\mathcal{H}$ permute, according to the Lemma. The Proposition now gives modularity.